# Ejecutar setTimeout una cantidad de veces específica

Tags: javascript

Quiero que el **setTimeout** se ejecute 5 veces cada 3 segundos, donde añado la cantidad para que funcione?

```js
function myFunction() {
  setTimeout(child, 3000);
}
```

Comment: 5 veces cada 3 segundos?

Comment: @Aprendiz sí, 5 veces cada 3 segundos.

Comment: A ver, que al parecer no está muy claro. ¿Quieres ejecutar 5 veces la función `setTimeOut` o quieres ejecutar 5 veces la función `child`? En todo caso, lo que necesitas es `setInterval`. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Crea otra función que ejecute 5 veces `child()`, lo puedes colocar en un ciclo `for` para no hace código repetitivo, incluso con `for ... of` que un for each sobre un objeto iterable, después lo llamas cada 3 segundos con `setInterval` así:

```js
function myFunction() {
  setInterval(five(), 3000);
}

function five() {
 for (var i of new Array(5) ) {
   child()
 }   
}

function child() {
  console.log('child')
}

myFunction()
```

Comment: Esto ejecutará la función `five()` 1 sola vez después de pasados 3 segundos. El OP no es muy claro, pero al parecer quiere que se repita "algo" 5 veces, cada 3 segundos. Saludos